# Creating 'for loop' of variables containing some value, in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

How can I create a for loop of a different variables in javascript that hold different values.

This a part of my code:-

```
<?php 
$phparray = array();
array.push($phparray, "//some value");
?>
<script type = "text/javascript>
var a = "<?php echo $phparray[0] ?>";
var b = "<?php echo $phparray[1]?>";
</script>
```

In this code, want a for loop instead of defining each element separately.
Also if possible, I want a variable which will hold values of both var a and var b.

Comment: first fix the issues in existing code. A script tag without an echo or variable name is undefined inside php

Comment: What does the array contain? What exactly should the resulting code look like? Consider using JSON and/or AJAX instead of this questionable method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) of php

its Object use with [**object.function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [**for..in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops .its `'Array'` use with [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) function

```
 <?php 
    $phparray = array();
    array.push($phparray, "//some value);
    ?>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>;
    console.log(arr)
    //use forloop or any other loop function
    </script>
```

Comment: remove the quotes and you do not need the parse

Comment: @prasad:- thanks it is working. But let me know how can I use for loop with this?

Comment: its returning `object` you could use any one of the [object function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want to. Instead, just dump it out as an array, and use the array in the JavaScript `for` loop:

```
<?php 
$phparray = array();
array.push($phparray, "some value");
// ...

<script type = "text/javascript>
var values = <?php echo json_encode($phparray) ?>;
// ...
</script>
?>
```

The browser will see

```
var values = ["some value", ...];
```

...and you'll be able to use it as a JavaScript array.